# SP Online & managed properties : How to render Enhanced Rich Text from Multiline Columns?

Tags: search, search-results, managed-property, crawled-property, office-dev-pnp

Hello fellow sharepointers !

**What I want to achieve :**

I created an Extension that displays a FAQ list. To retrieve FAQ items in this extension, I'm using PnP and the search() function. 
In this FAQ list, I have a column named Answer which is a Enhanced Rich Text Multiline column (so the user can add bold formatting, images and even gifs -which is very cool for producing tutorials/FAQ content.)

Everything is working fine, I got my items, no worries about it.

**What is the problem** :

I am just struggling with my Answer Multiline column.
In the list, the Answer column is filled with that sort of content (images, formatting, hyperlink etc), but I don't retrieve the rich text in my Extension, I only retrieve the content Plain Text.

**What I did** :

In the Sharepoint Admin, I've modified the Search Schema : I've taken the RefinableString52 managed property and mapped it to my crawled properties as such :
 In the "Mappings to crawled properties" section, I've kept the " **include content from all crawled properties**" option checked, and I mapped the Managed Property "RefinableString52" to two crawled properties :
"**ows_r_MTXT_didacticielAnswer**", and "**ows_didacticielAnswer**"

So, do you have any idea on **how I could get my Enhanced Rich text formatting** ?

I am sure it has something to do with crawled and mapped properties ! But I can't find what.

Thanks a lot for your hand ! Have a nice day ;)

Comment: Can you check the search schema for `didacticielAnswerOWSMTXT` managed property ?

Comment: Hello @GautamSheth ! I have no such managed property. (which is strange)
And even with that, I prefer to use RefinableStrings because they are queryable/Sortable and so on.. And I forgot to mention, I created the site columns under ContentTypeHub and then added them to a Content Type which is published